# when to return [] vs {} when creating a custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I am curious to when you should return an array to destructure and when you should return an object to destructure with custom hooks in react because as in many cases, I believe they will give you the same results.

```
return [name,age]
return {name,age}
```

Comment: It would just be a matter of preference tmk, you could see a difference while destructuring ..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for picking one over the other isn't really based on a behavioural difference. It's often (not always, please read this whole post!) because returning an array inverts control of the naming of each item in the return value to the user of the hook, without having to use aliases (due to how the array destructuring syntax is), which would be cumbersome in **certain cases (see below).**

Everything will update as normal whether it's an object or array -- it is not relevant to behaviour. It's relevant to just picking the most appropriate structure. And that varies depending on various aspects of the hook and how it will be used.

Imagine if `useState` returned an object and you had multiple state items:

```
const { state: stateItem1, setState: setStateItem1 } = useState()
const { state: stateItem2, setState: setStateItem2 } = useState()
```

Much more noise right? By using an array as the return value, we don't need all the object destructuring aliasing. That's why the React authors picked an array return value in this case. They are effectively using an array not for its list-like capabilities, but just because the syntactic sugar on destructuring an array is less noisy.

However, this doesn't mean you should go and use an array everywhere. It makes less sense the more properties you have as you are then expecting the consumer to understand the order. `useState` is small enough and well-known enough for this not to be a problem. It also is typically used multiple times in a component, which emphasized the need for nicer aliasing syntax.

Really, it only makes sense to use `[]` if you: have a small number of items; the array is fixed width and a well-defined order (i.e. a list of defined functions); and the purpose of the hook is so generic you expect it to be used many times in one component (so they need easy aliasing). This isn't a hard and fast rule, just guidelines.

Otherwise, use an object with named properties.

Everything I said is really about `{}` vs `[]` in the context of picking which to use for purposes of destructuring. Of course, if you have an array that is an array because it's the best data structure (e.g. it returns a list of users: `[{age: 30, name: 'user1'}, {age: 35, name: 'user2'}]`), then this is an overriding factor and you need to return an array. In these cases, the user of the hook wouldn't be destructuring/aliasing from it anyway as it would have variable  length and/or meaningless non-guaranteed order.

Your example is not this case though. A natural shape is an object with different types on each key (string for `name` and number for `age`) and those keys also together represent one conceptual item -  a single user. It doesn't make sense from a data structure perspective to say they are a "collection".

Comment: I feel like using an array is more error-prone since you're relying on element order to destructure. Sure prop-aliasing is an extra step but it's pretty minimal and not even necessary in many cases. I agree with you on the last point, if it's really an array of same 'type' elements, returning an array is fine. But in most cases I think returning an object is probably best practice.

Comment: I would agree usually you want an object. Picking array purely for destructuring uses has a very narrow set of use cases which I outline above. It just happens `useState` fits in them.

Comment: This is a perfect explanation. Pretty much exactly what I was looking for to help me decide how I want to return my custom hooks. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's really up to you to choose when to use one or the other.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html):

> Unlike a React component, a custom Hook doesn’t need to have a specific signature. We can decide what it takes as arguments, and what, if anything, it should return. In other words, it’s just like a normal function. Its name should always start with use so that you can tell at a glance that the rules of Hooks apply to it.

You might want to use `[]` for state since it will automatically be updated if the state changes in your hook. It would be useful if you only have a state to return. If you have more values to return, use an object `{}`.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed to know, especially cause I would have lost my mind wondering why state wasnt updating if i was returing an object.
Otherwise I dont really see much reason for the Array because as far as I know, you cant use any array methods like map etc... on the hook when calling it and you are just extracting the values from it into variables.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would update in an object; it should. But using the `[]` is better if you only need to return a state because you don't add an useless layer to your return object.

Comment: my previous comment I believe is inaccurate about the array as I could desctructure the entire array[...arrVariable] = useMyHook()  and then map over that variable.

Comment: @Sporadic It's not the case that state wont update if you return an object -- its not relevant. I have added an answer.